# ATL VS C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I start using the visual studio c++ express 2010 at home but there is no ATL and MFC in it.
How can I add ATL/MFC to visual studio c++ express 2010?

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for MFC and ATL for Express editions. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hs24szh9.aspx for comparison between editions.

Answer (score 2):

ATL, MFC, and OpenMP are not supported in Visual C++ Express 2010.

[Visual C++ Product Comparison (see the Libraries and Headers section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx?ppud=4)

Answer (score -1):

I guess, Microsoft would not mind much if you try to learn MFC at home. There is a possibility to work with existing MFC projects in VC++ Express: [How to compile MFC code in Visual C++ Express](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express)